# Cannot connect SQLalchemy with my postgreSQL server on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run databes on Docker container and connect it with my code.

This is my connection string:

```py
engine = create_engine('postgres+psycopg2://name:password@hostname:port/database_name')
```

As `host_name` I use IP address of my Linux where I installed docker container. I also checked if port on my machine is same in docker container. Ports are set to `5101:5101`.

After trying to connect this is error that is shown:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "IP of machine", port 5101 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Here is the Docker command I used:

```
docker run --name rule-creator-dat -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 10.10.50.8:5101:5101 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

(IP address is just example of my server)

Does somebody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that when ports are mapped in docker file port inside of the docker for PostgreSQL has to be `5432`. So the mapping should look `-p 5101:5432`.

Also there is no need to use IP address in port mapping.